# What would Socrates have said if the trolley problem was asked to him?

Tags: ethics, socrates, practical-ethics

Imagine a situation a wagon carrier asked to Socrates a variation of the Trolley Problem. What will be the Socrates' answer in terms of being just and being a good man?

Comment: You should state the trolley problem.  Or at least give a link.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolley_problem but I have no idea how Socrates would deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Socrates, at least in his portrayal in the early Platonic dialogs (generally viewed as closest to the historical Socrates), would be more inclined to ask such a question than answer it.  His typical approach was to take someone who felt a sense of certainty about some moral or philosophical issue, and to ask him a question that would introduce doubt about his beliefs.  If pressed on his own stance, he would profess ignorance.